# bezierPath in swift 3 on UIView, only curved line needed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When i draw a bezierPath in swift on UIView. I get straight line along with it. I only need the curved line is it possible to remove the straight line.

I can remove gray fill by: 
line.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

Not sure how i can remove the straight line

[image]

Code:

```
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: start)
    linePath.addLine(to: end)
    var dis = (end.x - start.x)/3.0
    linePath.addCurve(to: start,
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: start.x + dis, y: start.y + dis),
                  controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: end.x - dis, y: end.y - dis))

    line.path = linePath.cgPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //line.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    line.lineWidth = 4.0
    line.opacity = 0.6
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't close the path. When you close a bezier path it adds a straight line between the beginning and ending of the path. If you don't close the path then it should not do that. (However you can't fill a non-closed path, just stroke it.)

If that doesn't help you, you'll need to edit your question to show your code that creates and draws your path.

Comment: Hi @Duncan, i have updated the code. Even after removing close it is still drawing the straight line

Comment: Your code has an explicit command to draw a line from the start point to the end point: `linePath.addLine(to: end)` And it's written to draw a curve from the end to the start. Get rid of that `addLine` command, move to the endpoint first, and then do the call to add a curve from the end point to the start point (or move to the beginning of the curve, then rewrite your `linePath.addCurve` to add a curve from the beginning point to the ending point.)

Answer (score 4):

Please try the code below. Specify the start point and the end point and use pi of the trigonometric function to express the circle curve. If you want to use animation using these, please add the following code to UIView

[image: Example image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pi = CGFloat(Float.pi)
        let start:CGFloat = 0.0
        let end :CGFloat = pi
        
        // circlecurve
        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath();
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: CGPoint(x:self.view.frame.width/4, y:self.view.frame.height/4),
            radius: 300,
            startAngle: start,
            endAngle: end,
            clockwise: true
        )
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)   
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```